# How Many Google +1's Does a Website need in order for Google WebMaster's Tools to Show Characteristics?

Tags: google-search-console, google-plus-one, demographics

I have added the Google +1 Button to my website and discovered the new Social Activity section in Google WebMaster's Tools. Apparently, one of the interesting things you can learn about your audience is demographic data. But in GWT, the *Social Activity > Audience* section for my site (currently 127 +1's), says the following:

> Your site doesn’t have enough +1′s yet to show characteristics

But I'm not sure how many +1's is enough. Google's official [help page for the Audience section](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1198127&hl=en) offers little insight:

> The Audience page displays information about people who have +1'd your pages, including the total number of unique users, their location, and their age and gender.
>
> All information is anonymized; Google doesn't share personal information about people who have +1’d your pages. To protect privacy, Google won't display age, gender, or location data unless a certain minimum number of people have +1'd your content.

But what is that "certain minimum number"? I've tried Googling this but all I could find to date was [this page](http://www.im3.co.uk/blog/how-many-1s-do-i-need-to-show-characteristics/) which doesn't answer the question.

So how many +1's does a site need before GWT will show me audience demographic characteristics?

Answer (score 4):

Nobody knows how many you need yet. But before long someone will have enough +1's to get reporting in GWT and hopefully publish their findings. So keep Googling as it's only a matter of time before this happens.

Comment: What is the highest number of +1's that you are aware of, that GWT has been known to report so far? In other words, I would like to know _at least_ how many +1's I would need before GWT shows characteristics.

Comment: I think perhaps another reason might be "incomplete feature" or carefully considering the wider privacy/security implications of said feature.

Answer (score 2):

I have the information in Google and have 20 +1s this month and 65 overall.

Comment: i have 20+ this month but still saying "Your site doesn't have enough +1's yet to show characteristics." ?

Comment: @asiandata: How many +1s do you have overall?

Comment: I have nearly 300 but no information

Comment: @Tom Gullen: Is it possible that it's not a specific number but rather something more sophisticated such as a minimum amount of variety in the demographic data that has been collected?

Comment: @Asaph, it would have to be that, otherwise even a single +1 would reasonably be reported.